# fit image to div according to its width and height

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to fit image into div. But somehow image is not fitting. Take a look at div called as `node2`

I have put below properties to image

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;

}
```

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8oszbuc/39/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using max height and width, try using regular:

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

I also noticed in your fiddle, under CSS you had the following:

```
object-fit: contain;
```

You need to remove this as well.

Both of which will stretch the image both vertically and horizontally across the whole of the div.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
img {
  float: left;
  object-fit: fill;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and if you do not want to strecth your image then please add following css also:

```
#node2 {
  height: auto;
  width: 255px;
}
```

Please find [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d8oszbuc/44/)  here.

Comment: 71.42% global support

Answer (score 0):

if you want it 100% x 100% then, do it as background image of your div:

```
div{
    background-image: url('../images/yourimage.jpg');
    background-position: 0% 25%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```